# How to find center pixel value of bounding box in opencv python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, index-error

I'm trying to find the pixel intensity at the center of bounding box

TO achieve this I'm finding the center coordinates of bounding box and get the pixel intensity of that coordinate as shown below

```
img_read= cv2.imread(r'image.png')
cv2.rectangle(img_read,(xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymax),(0,0,255),3)
center_x = int((xmin+xmax)//2)
center_y = int((ymin+ymax)//2)
print(center_x,center_y)
cv2.circle(img_read,(center_x,center_y),50,(0,0,255),3)
print('Pixel intensity at:',img_read[center_x][center_y])
plt.imshow(img_read[:,:,::-1])
```

when I run this I get error as below

```
IndexError: index 859 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 815
```

but when I try to draw circle from that point with cv2.circle it draws circle without any errors
How can I access the pixel intensity value at point img_read[center_x][center_y]) ?
I tried with this as well img_read[center_x,center_y] but got same error

any help or suggestion to fix this issue will be appreciated thanks

Comment: `img_read[center_x][center_y]` -- numpy arrays use row-major indexing by default. You have the coordinates swapped.

Comment: Probably just need to transpose the x and y dims. `img_read[center_y, center_x]`

Comment: [tour], [ask]. google your error message. "IndexError... out of bounds" has TONS of explanations out there. you just have to find one. -- @DanMašek I believe you swapped the indices, same as OP did... or that's a straight quote from OP's code

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz -- it's a quote, to point out what bit of code I'm talking about, since OP didn't post a complete traceback.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Read the image & get the dimensions  
    img_read= cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Desktop\test_center_px.tiff")
    dimensions = img_read.shape
    h, w=dimensions[0], dimensions[1]            

#create the bounding box if necessary (not in mine)       
    domain = cv2.rectangle(img_read,(0,0),(w,h),(255,0,0),20)
    plt.imshow(domain,cmap='gray')
    
    center_x = w/2
    center_y = h/2

#all we need to do is pass in the (x, y)-coordinates as image[y, x]
    (b, g, r) = img_read[np.int16(center_y), np.int16(center_x)]
    print("Color at center pixel is - Red: {}, Green: {}, Blue: {}".format(r, g, b))
```

OUTPUT:
Color at center pixel is - Red: 152, Green: 152, Blue: 152

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
img_read[center_y,center_x]
```

Comment: not sure why that's getting downvotes. your answer may be a bit terse but it captures the essence of OP's mistake: indexing order is row (y) first, then column (x)

Comment: Without some explanation of what the actual problem is, why the OP should "try" this, and what they should learn in order to avoid the same mistake in the future (ideally with some reference to documentation), I don't really consider this low-effort post very valuable.

Comment: then perhaps tapping the [answer] sign would help